# Image control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am trying to display image in .aspx page, for that i write code like this in page_load event ,

```
Image1.ImageUrl = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.JPEG";
```

but image is not displaying, can you help me thank you.

Comment: You can use
[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to map local path to relative path.

Comment: problem is with path. It should be a virtual path. Or path of you web application. Like "http://www.sitename.com/images/filename" or it should be a relative path "~/Images/Bird1.jpg"

Comment: Your application may not have access to the mentioned location @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.JPEG";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is problem with the path of image ...you need to give relative path for image rather than physical path

something like this

```
Image1.ImageUrl="~/Images/Bird1.jpg"
```

here image is in the Images folder of the application. i.e.which is part of project

First create a Images folder in your Solution Explorer. Then store your image in that folder and refer like as below.

**Example**

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Bird1.jpg" />
```

Check in deatil : [Image Control Example](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.ca/2008/10/image-control-example.html)

Comment: Image1.ImageUrl ="\\192.162.1.2\C$\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.JPEG" can i write like this

Comment: @Ssasidhar - no you cannot do that ..you need to provide the relative path only as i did in my answer ...

Comment: So, must and should image should be in my solution explorere

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your local path as the path to your image, instead place the web site url with a relative path to the image

Comment: "\\192.162.1.2\C$\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.JPEG"

Comment: no you cannotuser the ip like you did. you can do Server.MpaPath("~/SamplePictures/Koala.JPEG/')

Comment: the image koala.Jpeg which is not in my project folder i mean not in solution explorer, is this possible to access that

Comment: Yes, you should create a Generic Handler (*.ashx) that will retrieve the image from its location and return in as a buffer to the client. Then place the image URL as your handler.